# creating a XML tree in java and convert it to json object

Tags: java, xml, json

I tried to create the tree also able to convert to json. But for only one xpath. When I tried to implement multiple xpath, I could not get desired output. Here I am sharing my implementation

```
private static Document addElemtbypath(List<String> pathList1,
            List<String> elementList) {

        Document doc = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory docfactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docfactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Tree");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);

            for (int i = 0; i < pathList1.size(); i++) {
                String pathList = pathList1.get(i);
                String element = elementList.get(i);

                List<String> xpath = new LinkedList<>();
                String[] parts = pathList.split("/");
                for (int j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
                    xpath.add(parts[j]);

                }
                System.out.println(xpath);

                Node node = doc.getDocumentElement();
                Document dom = node.getOwnerDocument();
                System.out.println(node);

                for (int k = 0; k < xpath.size(); k++) {
                    XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
                    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(xpath.get(k),
                            doc.getDocumentElement(), XPathConstants.NODESET);

                    if (nodes.getLength() != 0) {
                        //node = (Node) nodes;   // getting class cast exception
                        continue;                

                    } else {
                        node = node
                                .appendChild(dom.createElement(xpath.get(k)));
                    }
                }
                node.appendChild(dom.createTextNode(element));
                // System.out.println(nodes);
                System.out.println(dom);
                System.out.println(node);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return doc;

    }
```

and the output I got is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Tree>
    <Product>
        <Organization>
                <RegisteredDetail>
                            <something>product1</something>
                </RegisteredDetail>
        </Organization>
    </Product>
    <Organization>
    <RegisteredDetail>product2</RegisteredDetail>
    </Organization>
</Tree>
```

As you can see nodes are repeated, I don't know where I was wrong. My desired output should be look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Tree>
    <Product>
        <Organization>
                <RegisteredDetail>
                            product2
                            <something>product1</something>
                </RegisteredDetail>
        </Organization>
    </Product>
</Tree>
```

In some way or the other I am making some mistake while iterating for the second time.

Comment: Are you asking about Java or JavaScript ? You do know that these two are similar like Ham nad Hamster ?

Comment: I am asking about java. The above code is in javascript, which I already wrote, I just want to know similar type of method in java, so that I can avoid duplicate node while creating the dom. Check my previous question and its ans. @endriu_l